# Ubuntu 14.10 uses VESA:DVST instead of my AMD driver

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, xorg

I have the latest AMD Omega 15.5 drivers and installed them using the .run file that AMD had available for download. But my details for graphics says I'm using VESA:DVST as my driver, but Borderlands 2, Garry's Mod, and even  `fgl_glxgears` works and gears gave me a 56 to 68 FPS rating but my Steam games are like 10 to 20 FPS on this driver.

Here's is my Details:
[image]

and the Drivers list:
[image]

```
kyle@kyle-HP-Envy-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci -k | grep VGA -A2
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity [Radeon HD 7420G] 
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 182d 
Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep VGA -A2` terminal command. Also you can run `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`.

Comment: `kyle@kyle-HP-Envy-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci -k | grep VGA -A2
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity [Radeon HD 7420G]
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 182d
 Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci` that was `lspci -k | grep VGA -A2`

Answer (score 0):

Just run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

and you will get correct output there.

Comment: mesa-utils is already installed on my laptop

Comment: Then it does not recognize this new driver. There is nothing to worry about.

Comment: So, ubuntu 14.10 is just hiding the fact that it is installed and just giving a generic driver name then?

Comment: It is not hiding, but just gives incorrect output there. Anyway 14.10 will reach end of life less than in 2 month. In 15.04 it must be OK. And this output does not affect anything.